# Conditional method calling conditional method not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, logging, conditional-statements

I am trying to enhance my Logger class with some conditionals to control what to log and where to log. I've got two kinds of logging functions:

```
public static class Logger
{
    [Conditional("Logging"), Conditional("VerboseLogging")]
    public static void Log(string msg, string filename)
    {
        // log to file
    }

    [Conditional("VerboseLogging")]
    public static void VerboseLog(string msg, string filename)
    {
        Log(msg, filename); // just defer call to Log(string msg)
    }
}
```

However, running the following program

```
#define Logging
#define VerboseLogging

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Log("Logging", "");
    Logger.VerboseLog("VerboseLogging", "");
}
```

yields only the output "Logging", missing "VerboseLogging".

Debugging the application showed that VerboseLogging indeed does get called, but it does not call `Log(msg, filename)`. The debugger simply jumps right over the function call to the end of the `VerboseLog()` function.

When I remove the conditionals from the `Log(string msg)` method, it works.

Does anybody have a clue as to why this happens or what to do so it will be called?

Comment: I built the app exactly as you have it and everything worked as it should; I am unable to recreate the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Perhaps the binary has not rebuilt properly? Have you tried doing a clean build?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that several times. Of course there is more to my application, reading a CSV, logging to a file etc. I don't understand why it call's VerbosLog(...), but jumps over the call to Log() in body of VerboseLog().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you need to define `Logging` and `VerboseLogging` in your `Logger`
 file also, because `VerboseLog` will not call `Log` if `Logging` is not defined there.

To add a project-wide conditional define, right click on your Project, and select Project Properties. Then go to the Build tab and enter "Logging, VerboseLogging" to  the "Conditional compilation symbols" text box.

Answer (score 0):

Are the conditionals not upside down there? i.e.

```
[Conditional("Logging")]
public static void Log(string msg, string filename) { }

[Conditional("Logging"), Conditional("VerboseLogging")]
public static void VerboseLog(string msg, string filename) {
    Log(msg, filename); // just defers call to Log()
}
```

Comment: No, i don't believe so. The OP wants Log to occur in both situations but VerboseLog to only occur for the VerboseLogging condition.

Comment: Regardless, he still has both VerboseLogging and Logging defined.

Comment: Jeff Yates is right. Log should occur in both cases, VerboseLog only if VerboseLogging is defined.

Comment: @Josh G: Yeah, but that does do no harm. Even if I only define VerboseLogging, it's still not working :(

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96.aspx has some info about the Logical AND/OR behaviour of Conditionals but from my reading of that page... your example should be working

Answer (score 0):

No real help, but the code you posted works fine here for me (.NET 3.5 SP1 console application). Of course I need to remove the filename parameter since your calls in main don't supply it, but other than that both defines gave me both logs and removing the verbose define only logged "Logging".

Applying Occam's razor to the problem: Since the code you posted obviously isn't direct from your source (no body for log method and the missing parameters) are you *sure* that you've spelt the defines correctly in your original source? Other than that I have no idea why it isn't working for you...

Comment: Thank you for testing the Code! I copied "VerboseLogging" everywhere, still does not work. Oddly enough, the VerboseLog()-method DOES get called, but it does no call Log() inside the body. It jumps over it.

Comment: Ah, now that the real answer has been posted I can see that cutting corners and putting all the classes in a single source file was not the most intelligent way to test this problem. Live and learn I guess...